# SwiftUI decoding image from String(Base64)

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, base64, decoding

I have an image in the string (base 64) how I can decode this string for Image() using SwiftUI.

Know I am using this format:

```
Image(imageFromAppGroup(key: "image0")).resizable().frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .background(Color(red: 0.218, green: 0.215, blue: 0.25))
```

I need a past base 64 images instead of "image0". How I can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `UIImage` for this:

```
let str = "IMAGE"
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: str)!)!)
```

You will not want to force unwrap with `!` here, so you should handle that too:

```
let str = "IMAGE"

if let data = Data(base64Encoded: str), let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
} else {
    let _ = print("FAIL")
}
```

You could also create an `Image` extension:

```
extension Image {
    init?(base64String: String) {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else { return nil }
        guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else { return nil }
        self = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    }
}

/* ... */

var body: some View {
    Image(base64String: str)
}
```

Comment: According to stackoverflow.com/a/60732521/2926577 , UIImage should be avoided in SwiftUI because " it's like using objective c code in swift which doesn't make sense of releasing a new language". Is this accurate? If yes, is there a way to decode base64 into something that's acceptable by Image() omitting UIImage?

Comment: @user2926577 No, using `UIImage` is not bad at all if used correctly. In SwiftUI, the main thing is to not initialize a `UIImage` in a view init or body, especially the body. This is because if the init takes a while, the view is slow to be created. If the `UIImage` is created in the body, it will be recreated _every_ time the view reloads which is expensive. Instead, create the image in `onAppear`, set it to a `@State` variable, then create the SwiftUI `Image` in the body.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```swift
extension Image {
  init?(base64String: String) {
    guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else { return nil }
    #if os(macOS)
    guard let image = NSImage(data: data) else { return nil }
    self.init(nsImage: image)
    #elseif os(iOS)
    guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return nil }
    self.init(uiImage: image)
    #else
    return nil
    #endif
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Image(base64String: base64string)
```

Comment: Good idea of supporting for macOS too, but I wouldn't create an init like that without an explicit label. `base64String` gives context, and also `Image` already has an `Image(_:)` init, so this could cause issues.